# How to change the state in Adobe Flex, using ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

I`m really new to Flex and ActionScript so please be patient with me.

I want to implement this script: **tinyurl.com/yafqrqb**
...that is doing this "magic" : **tinyurl.com/y9qg32r**

...but I want to tweak it a little on **InfoWindowTabbedComponent**. To be more precisely I`m trying to insert links in that tabs, and when you click one the state will change.

You can see my custom **InfoWindowTabbedComponent at the end of the post** As you can see, right now I have 2 functions that open url`s.

What I`m trying to do is to change this:

**var adobeURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.microsoft.com" );
    navigateToURL(adobeURL, "_self");**

Into  something that change the current state.

Can you please help me?

Here`s my custom InfoWindowTabbedComponent: http://pastebin.com/f387bc3b9

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. If you just want to set the selected Tab, instead of calling navigateToURL() set myTabNavigator.selectedIndex (or selectedChild)

If you really want to change the state, each component has a currentState property, but then you would have to define the states first (via the  tag)

And if you really want to navigateToURL() you could navigate to javascript:somefunction() and then set the application state via ExternalInterface, but that would be horribly circumstantial.

Cheers,
Jörg